# IOS - The correct way for using #import classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, import

I am writing a test project to learn to write everything in code. I want to do this way so that I can better understand what the Elements in Storyboard do for me behind the scene's

In my project I have several UIViewControllers which share the same UI elements. For Example I have a UITool bar at the top of the screen with several buttons in it.

Now I want to put that UIToolbar in a separate class so that I do not have to write it all out or copy n paste it in every controller.

Now I know I can achieve this by doing this:

```
#import "General_Add_ons.h" //the UIToolbar is properly set up in this file

@interface FirstViewController : General_Add_ons
```

and then I just use `[self topToolBar];` //topToolBar is the name of the toolbar

Now I just want to clarify is this the best and or only way to this?

Somehow I feel I should be able to do this:

```
    General_Add_ons *gao = [[General_Add_ons alloc] init];
    [gao topToolbar];
```

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? The first way seems to be limiting in case I have multiple external classes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seem correct.  If you have several `UIViewController` instances that need the same UI elements or other controller code, you can put those elements in a `UIViewController` subclass.  In your case, I believe the class `General_Add_ons` is the `UIViewController` from which your subclasses will inherit.

This class (your `General_add_ons`) should have a property for the reusable toolbar, e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIToolbar *toolbar;
```

As an aside, class names in Cocoa, by convention are:  prefix+capitalized words without underscores.  Apple has a great reference on [naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html).

**EDIT**

For clarification, you can subclass your custom subclass as many times as you need.  For example in my code, I have a class `CCFViewController` that encapsulates common properties and behaviors that I want all of my view controllers to have.  In the project, then, all of the view controllers inherit from that parent controller.  Similarly, your toolbar will live in the superclass and the other controllers inherit from it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the naming conventions - I do use the proper ones when making an official app:-) so if I understand you correctly the first way is the best way?

Comment: Yes, I think the first way is what you want.  In the second case, you are instantiating the superclass directly.  Since it sounds like `General_add_ons` is a `UIViewController` subclass that would be unnecessary.

Comment: Ok - sorry to bother one more time, say if I have multiple UiViewControllers cuz I want to organise things in a certain way than the 1st way is only going to allow me to do 1 subclass right? I can't inherit from multiple classes??

Comment: If `General_add_ons` is a `UIViewController` subclass, then you can subclass it as many times as needed.  You can even subclass the subclasses, etc.  As to your second question - correct, ObjC doesn't do multiple inheritance. Thankfully.

Comment: Cool I think I got it:-) more practise:-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but i think you should try it this way:

```
General_Add_ons *gao = [[General_Add_ons alloc] init];
[gao.topToolbar anypossiblemethodcall];
```